# Create a program that calculates vector resultants with both cartesian coordinates and polar coordinates

Tags: python, vector

I need to create a program that calculates the vector resultant but I need to allow the user to choose between polar and cartesian coordinates. This is what I have so far but it gives me errors and I am not sure what to do to ask the user both x,y coordinates and how to make the program stop after the vectors have been entered. Please help, I don't know much about this!

import math
#calculate vector components and change from polar to cartesian and vice versa

````
def fxcomponent(x, y):              # to find cartesian x
  number = x
  y = math.cos(math.degrees(y))
  result = number * y
  return result

def fycomponent(x, angle):          #to find cartesian y
  number = x 
  angle = math.sin(math.degrees(angle))
  result = number * angle
  return result

def polar_length(r,t):              #to find polar lenght
    number = r
    length =((r**2) + (t**2))
    result = math.sqrt(number)
    return result
    
def polar_angle(r,theta):           #to find polar angle
    result = math.atan2(theta,r)
    return result


#prompts
prompt = 'Hi!'
type_coor = input('Enter the type of coordinate you will use: use p for polar \n enter c for cartesian')
vector_number = input('Enter the number of vectors you will be adding: ')
i = 0
while i <= vector_number:
    if type_coor == 'p':                     #if polar values are entered
        print('What is the r value?:')
        x, angle = [int(x) for x in input('>').split()]
        result = fxcomponent(x, angle)
        print('The x component of %d at %d° is: %d' % (x, angle, result))
    elif type_coor == 'p':
        print ('What is the value of the angle?:')
        y, angle = [int(x) for x in input('>').split()]
        result = fycomponent(y, angle)
        print('The y component of %d at %d° is: %d' % (y, angle, result))```
````

Answer (score 0):

there are a lot of different error sources here, this is a difficult task...

First, this code will break if someone enters something unexpected,

to fix this you can use if conditions to check if input values are ok like this :

```py
variable = input('enter "c" or "p" \n>>')
if variable not in ['c','p']: # to check if variable is in the list
    exit() # quit the program 

# and for a number (integer only !!!)
variable = input('enter a number \n>>')
if !variable.isnumeric():
    exit()
```

then, I don't know much about the math you use here, but, if your 4 functions at the top are correct, then you should ask for each variable with a different input and use your `if ... elif` only to differenciate between `type_coord == 'p'` and `type_coord == 'c'`

something like this works, but it is only with integers and I believe this is not what you want :

```py
#prompts
prompt = 'Hi!'

type_coor = input('Enter the type of coordinate you will use: \nuse p for polar \nenter c for cartesian \n("q" for quit):\n>> ')
if type_coor not in ['c', 'p']:
    print('coordinate type must be "c" or "p"')
    exit() # quitting the program

vector_number = input('Enter the number of vectors you will be adding: \n>> ')
if vector_number.isnumeric() == False:
    print('must be integer')
    exit()
vector_number = int(vector_number)

i = 0
while i < vector_number:
    if type_coor == 'p':                     #if polar values are entered
        r = input('What is the r value?: \n>>')
        if r.isnumeric() == False:
            print('r must be integer')
            exit()
        r = int(r)

        t = input('What is the t value?: \n>>')
        if t.isnumeric() == False:
            print('theta must be integer')
            exit()
        t = int(t)

        theta = input('What is the theta value?: \n>>')
        if theta.isnumeric() == False:
            print('theta must be integer')
            exit()
        theta = int(theta)
        
        length = polar_length(r, t)
        angle = polar_angle(r,theta)
        print('length = %d' % (length))
        print('angle = %d' % (angle))
    
    elif type_coor == 'c':              # if cartesian values are entered
        # do the same for cartesian coordinates
    i += 1
```

if you want to work with decimal values, then the code gets even more complicated. For each float value you should do something like this :

```py
variable = input('enter a decimal \n>> ')
try:
    variable = float(variable)
except ValueError:
    print('not a decimal')
    exit()
```

... And the final step, is to replace all the `if` input condition checking by `while` loops that ask the user to enter a value until this value is correct...

Hope this helps, have fun!

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I was able to fix it with your first example but when I tried p it gave me this error:  if vector_number.isnumeric() == False:
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isnumeric'. Do you happen to know why?

Comment: you need to transform your input in `int` **after** you checked that it is numeric, otherwise you will get that error